# How to name a transaction in Apache Camel / Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, jta

I am working on a software written with Spring Boot and Apache Camel. I am having some issues with transactions handling so I have set the logging for org.springframework.transaction to the DEBUG level.
All the transactions created have name [null]. Is there a way to change that?

```
2018-10-04 17:23:03.250 DEBUG 4400 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.t.jta.JtaTransactionManager : Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
```